# js - calculate total using dynamic variables

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I need to calculate a price total based off checkboxes which toggle price components. Basically, I have this logic:

```
comp1 = 100
comp2 = 200
comp3 = 300

totalPrice = ->
    if $('#checkboxA').hasClass('checked')
        comp1 = comp1
    else
        comp1 = 0

    if $('#checkboxB').hasClass('checked')
        comp2 = comp2
    else
        comp2 = 0

    if $('#checkboxC').hasClass('checked')
        comp3 = comp3
    else
        comp3 = 0

    return comp1 + comp2 + comp3
```

But it feels kinda awkward. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

```
price1 = 100
price2 = 200
price3 = 300

totalPrice = ->
    total = 0
    total += price1 if $('#checkboxA').hasClass 'checked'
    total += price2 if $('#checkboxB').hasClass 'checked'
    total += price3 if $('#checkboxC').hasClass 'checked'
    total
```

If there are more prices, maybe an array to store them (along with its corresponding checkbox css class) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to find all the checked elements at once, then convert the [matched elements to an array](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/), and then use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do the summing. If you stash the prices in an object indexed by checkbox ID then the `reduce` callback becomes trivial. Something like this:

```
comp =
    checkboxA: 100
    checkboxB: 200
    checkboxC: 300
summer = (m, e) -> m + comp[e.id]    
sum = $('#checkboxA.checked, #checkboxB.checked, #checkboxC.checked')
    .toArray()
    .reduce(summer, 0)
```

If you're certain that only those checkboxes will have `checked` class then you can simplify to:

```
sum = $('.checked').toArray().reduce(summer, 0)
```

or if you can add a class to the checkboxes to group them:

```
sum = $('.someGroupingClass.checked').toArray().reduce(summer, 0)
```

or if they're all inside a common parent:

```
sum = $('whatEverTheParentSelectorIs .checked').toArray().reduce(summer, 0)
```

You could also embed the prices in data attributes, throw out `comp`, and replace `summer` with something like:

```
summer = (m, e) -> m + $(e).data('price')
```

You could also use a loop instead of `toArray` and `reduce`:

```
sum = 0
for e in $('.checked') # Use whatever selector you need in here
    sum += $(e).data('price')
```